# MYSQL to SQL - Limit in Update

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I try to change my code from MYSQL to SQL and i got an error (SQL Syntax 'Limit').

So i tried to change my query and update with "TOP" but seems to work only with SELECT.

So, how can i change this MYSQL query :

```
$fct="UPDATE `users` SET `STREAM_TITRE` = '$STREAM_TITRE',`STREAM_URL` = '$STREAM_URL',`STREAM_DESC` = '$STREAM_DESC',`STREAM_GENRE` = '$STREAM_GENRE' WHERE `ID` =$IDSESS LIMIT 1";
```

Here is my SQL Code without Limit :

```
$fct="UPDATE users SET STREAM_TITRE = '$STREAM_TITRE', STREAM_URL = '$STREAM_URL', STREAM_DESC = '$STREAM_DESC', STREAM_GENRE = '$STREAM_GENRE' WHERE ID = '$IDSESS'";
```

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that `SQL Syntax 'Limit'` is your complete error? And what is the problem? It seems to me you have a query that doesn't work, and have one that does, so what is the problem is you have one that works?

Comment: What does the query look like if you print $fct?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The documentation I've seen states that you can use TOP with UPDATE. Does it simply not work, or do you get an error message?

Comment: What do you mean with "to SQL"? SQL is a language that is also used by MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very clear which version of your query is working and which is not - and in what DBMS.

If `ID` is of char or varchar type, you are missing some quotes in the `LIMIT` version. Although MySQL is not very picky and you won't have many issues, with or without quotes:

```
$fct = "
  UPDATE users 
  SET STREAM_TITRE = '$STREAM_TITRE'
    , STREAM_URL = '$STREAM_URL'
    , STREAM_DESC = '$STREAM_DESC'
    , STREAM_GENRE = '$STREAM_GENRE' 
  WHERE ID = $IDSESS              --<-- this should be '$IDSESS' , right?
                                  ----- or $IDSESS , depending on the datatype
  LIMIT 1
       ";
```

Note: The `LIMIT n` works in MySQL and PostgreSQL, but not in some other DBMS. Plus, I don't think you really need it anyway, as the `ID` is probably the Primary Key of the table.

If you are trying to convert the statement from MySQL to SQL-Server, you should not use the backquotes and replace `LIMIT 1` with `TOP (1)`:

```
$fct = "
  UPDATE TOP (1) users 
  SET STREAM_TITRE = '$STREAM_TITRE'
    , STREAM_URL = '$STREAM_URL'
    , STREAM_DESC = '$STREAM_DESC'
    , STREAM_GENRE = '$STREAM_GENRE' 
  WHERE ID = $IDSESS             
       ";
```

Comment: Changed it thanks. If you find a SQL Version, it would be perfect but thanks ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL version"? Microsoft SQL-Server?